# char[] to uint32_t not working properly

Tags: c, byte

I am using the following to convert a `char[4]` to a `uint32_t`.

```
frameSize = (uint32_t)(frameSizeBytes[0] << 24) | (frameSizeBytes[1] << 16) | (frameSizeBytes[2] << 8) | frameSizeBytes[3];
```

`frameSize` is a `uint32_t` variable, and `frameSizeBytes` is a `char[4]` array. When the array contains, for example, the following values (in hex)

```
00 00 02 7b
```

`frameSize` is set to 635, which is the correct value. This method also works for other combinations of bytes, with the exception of the following

```
00 00 9e ba
```

for this case, `frameSize` is set to 4294967226, which, according to [this website](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter), is incorrect, as it should be 40634 instead. Why is this behavior happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `char` type is signed in your specific implementation and undergoes integer promotion with most operators. Use a cast to `unsigned char` where the signed array elements are used.

**EDIT:** actually as pointed out by Olaf in the comment, you should actually prefer casts to `unsigned int` (assuming common 32-bit `unsigned int`) or `uint32_t` to avoid potential undefined behavior with the `<< 24` shift operation.

Comment: `unsigned char` will also be promoted to `int` where shifting into the sign-bit is implementation defined. The correct way would be to cast the `char`s to `uint32_t` before the shift. And the array should be `uint8_t`, not `char` or `unsigned char`.

Comment: This answer would be improved by showing some specific code, because of the first point made in Olaf's comment

Comment: Sorry, but I strongly disagree about "assuming common 32-bit unsigned int". I'm very confident that still most systems in the world use 16 bit `int`. You forget about the plethora of embedded 8 or 16 bit MCUs. IIRC, they still outnumber the 32bit world by far.

Comment: @Olaf 32-bit int is still pretty common... And I'm totally aware there are more MCUs currently in the world with 16-bit int than with 32-bit int.

Comment: (From my understanding "common" implies a majority. Btw.: 32 bis has a growing market share actually, mostly due to the Cortex-M0). But I'll leave it at that.) Anyway, using `stdint.h` types is always the preferred way than relying on a specific width of the standard types. Even more, as OP already uses this as output type (I would care less if assembling a 16 bit type - for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 1):

To keep things tidy I'd suggest an inline function along the lines of:

```
static inline uint32_t be_to_uint32(void const *ptr)
{
    unsigned char const *p = ptr;
    return p[0] * 0x1000000ul + p[1] * 0x10000 + p[2] * 0x100 + p[3];
}
```

Note: by using an `unsigned long` constant this code avoids the problem of `unsigned char` being promoted to signed `int` and then having the multiplication/shift cause integer overflow (an annoying historical feature of C).  Of course you could also use `((uint32_t)p[0]) << 24` as suggested by Olaf.